# How to identify process accesing usb port (scale)?

Tags: osx, usb

I'd like to identify through terminal which processes are using the scale connected to my mac, I need to kill those processes or clean the port to be used only by my app.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried lsof?